# The grid on the 3D-view is broken

Tags: 3d-view, gpu

[image: Viewport is broken]

The 3D-view is broken? It has weird artifacts on the grid. This happened after upgrading from an NVIDIA RTX 3070 to an AMD RX 7900 XT. I am currently on V23.4.3 for the AMD Software: Adrenaline Edition, which is the latest version as of 4/20/2023.

[image: AMD Driver Version Status]

This happens on all the blend files I have and any new ones that I open.
I made sure to uninstall the NVIDIA drivers before I Installed the AMD GPU and its drivers.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, have a nice day.

Comment: That definitely looks like a GPU, Driver, or OpenGL error (or any combination of the three). When you removed your old drivers, did you remove them using DDU?

Comment: What is DDU? I used the add/remove program thing from windows.

Comment: Display Driver Uninstaller - it's the _"proper"_  way to remove drivers when switching cards to ensure no conflicts or subsequent headaches - https://www.wagnardsoft.com/display-driver-uninstaller-ddu-

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a go and reinstall my drivers to see if that helps. Thank you for the info.

Comment: I get the same issue after uninstalling the driver and reinstalling it. Maybe it's just an issue with my GPU? But then I only have this issue in Blender. I use Solidworks and some other 3d programs and don't have any issues there. I am using Blender 3.5. I'm going to try 3.5.1 to see if maybe that fixes it and I'll try to go back to 3.4 as well.

Comment: Yeah. If the driver re-install didn't work, my next step would be a blender re-install as well.

Comment: Looks like it's still happening, regardless of what version of Blender I am on. I have tried 3.3.6, 3.4.1, and 3.5.1 and it still hasn't gone away. I think maybe it's my GPU.